# How to provide a header to a function in mocha test in node.js

Tags: node.js, http, mocha.js

I am trying to unit test the validate function

test function:

```
it('validating request', function(done) {
    var API = new API(Id, key , List);
    assert.isTrue(API.validate());

    done();
  });
```

main api:

```
API.prototype.validate = function validate(req, res) {

  var api_req = req.headers['reqH'];
  if (api_req == null || api_req == '') {
    res.send("Error:");
    return;
  }
```

I am getting the following error:
Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line you use `headers` on `req` which is one of the parameters of the function

```
var api_req = req.headers['reqH'];
```

but when you call the `validate` function, you didn't pass any parameters to it:

```
assert.isTrue(API.validate());
```

so `req` and `res` are `undefined` for this call